# map function not returning react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React.
Here I am getting values from props. If both names are the same I want to show a button else I want to return another function.
As i tried map function im getting the console but its not returning button. Below is the code i have tried . Can anyone help me

```js
showButton() {
  const { product } = this.props;
  const { cartName: { items } } = this.props;
  let currentproduct = product.name;
  items.map(function (items) {
    if (items.name == currentproduct) {
      console.log('Name', items.name, currentproduct);
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="ProductContainer">
            <button
              id="add"
              onClick={this.clickAddCart}
            >  {"Add to cart"}
            </button>
          </div>

        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (<div>{this.renderAction()}</div>)
    }
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="ProductSection">
      {this.showButton()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return *items.map* from the showButton function. Like this:

```
showButton() {
   /* code */
   return items.map(function(items) {
         /* code */
   });
```

Comment: Hi i tried to add like this     `return items.map(function(items) {
                return <>{this.renderAction()}</>
            
          });`    its not able to get renderAction() in this case . it throws error

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is return the jsx from the showButton function

for that you need to add return before your map even though you are having return inside the map but it just returns inside the map and gets assigned to variable to which map is assigned if you have one

```
  return items.map(function(items) {/*logic*/}
```

you can probably do like this:

```
const result = item.map(function(items){.....}
```

and at the end just do

```
return result;
```

Comment: i tried like this
 `return items.map(function(items) { if(items.name == currentproduct){return{this.renderAction()}</>} });`   
in this case it is not able to identify renderAction()  -@aravind

Comment: what do you mean by no able to identify.. can you put it in a sandbox so that it will be easy for us to help

Comment: this.renderAction  should call another function but when i do the map it is not getting that renderAction function . instead it is showing undefined even though it is available . @aravind_reddy

Comment: what does your renderAction look like ?

Comment: renderAction has increment and decrement function .So if name is same want to show Add button or it should call renderAction which has  + 1 - which is a common function . @aravind_reddy